# Universal Google Analytics Event Tracking Help (Form submission and tracking)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics

Implementing universal google analytics on my site and need to track the number of people who visit my site but do NOT fill out my donation form. Basically trying to get a more robust abandonment rate number. All information/tutorials I'm finding are from the old analytics version.

Any insight, Stack Geniuses?

Comment: you do not need a genius here. Just about 2:45 minutes of your precious time to learn how to [measure your site objectives](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en).

Comment: You can achieve this by tracking who does fill out donation forms and then analysing the data to filter these out.